# SAS: Table is sorted correctly, but graph is sorted incorrectly

Tags: graph, charts, sas

I thought this would be simple enough to figure out, but I have not been able to address the issue.

1. My graph is sorted by best_change, but is ascending instead of descending
   (despite being pre-sorted in the original excel file). I have tried adding the GROUPORDER argument, but that is not working.

---

```
%let gpath=C:\;
%let dpi=200;
ods html close;
ods listing gpath="&gpath" image_dpi=&dpi;


proc print data=TESTCODE (obs=46);
run;
ods html close;

/*--Change in Tumor Size--*/
ods listing style=listing;
ods graphics / reset width=10in height=10in imagename='TumorSize';
title 'Change in Tumor Size';
title2 'ITT Population';
proc sgplot data=TESTCODE nowall noborder;
  styleattrs datacolors=(cxbf0000 cx4f4f4f) datacontrastcolors=(black);
  vbarparm category= best_change response= best_change / grouporder = DESCENDING group=best_response datalabel=best_response
             datalabelattrs=(size=5 weight=bold) groupdisplay=cluster clusterwidth=1;
  refline 20 -30 / lineattrs=(pattern=shortdash);
  xaxis display=none;
  yaxis values=(80 to -100 by -20);
  keylegend / title='' location=inside position=topright across=1 border;
run;
```

Here is my test code that is being processed. The headers of the columns: Best_change = BC, subjid = SJ, PFS_day = Pd, PFS_months = Pm, Censor = C, Best_response = BR

```
BC  SJ  Pd  Pm  C   BR
92  23  58  3       PR
91  55  308 11      SD
87  40  383 12      PD
77  45  66  9   1   PR
74  35  56  11      SD
68  2   179 1       PD
67  41  348 3   1   SD
64  25  28  7       PD
61  37  156 5   1   SD
59  10  316 11      SD
56  12  98  9   1   PR
44  19  283 3       PD
44  46  78  10  1   SD
43  34  392 13  1   SD
35  9   214 11  1   PR
35  50  199 9       SD
25  47  302 1       PD
14  52  133 7       SD
11  33  24  4       SD
10  14  343 3       SD
5   31  244 1       SD
1   30  366 7   1   PR
-1  28  369 6       SD
-4  44  146 9       SD
-4  15  109 5       SD
-5  51  203 6   1   SD
-9  38  314 5       SD
-11 43  30  11  1   SD
-18 16  156 5   1   PR
-20 13  36  1       SD
-23 20  190 7       SD
-24 24  332 12      SD
-25 48  309 6   1   SD
-26 17  179 4       SD
-29 54  140 1   1   SD
-30 18  280 9       SD
-31 21  295 3   1   SD
-40 49  114 13  1   SD
-48 5   33  11      PD
-49 40  217 2       SD
-53 53  361 12      SD
-55 26  269 2       SD
-56 42  111 4   1   SD
-59 32  61  2       PR
-60 39  56  4   1   SD
-60 36  388 11      SD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "discreteorder=data" to your axis statement

```
xaxis display=none discreteorder=data ;
```